# $fromInput.datepicker is not a function yadcf on datatables

Tags: yadcf

I am trying to use a range_date column in yadcf, but I get:

```
$fromInput.datepicker is not a function
```

My code:

```
var table = $('#{{ table.opts.id }}').dataTable({
        "buttons": [
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],  
         ....
         }).yadcf([
        {
          column_number: 0,
          filter_type: "range_date",
          date_format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
          filter_delay: 500
        },
        {
          column_number: 1,
          filter_type: "text",
          filter_delay: 500
        },
        {
            column_number: 2,
            filter_type: "text",
            filter_delay: 500
        },
        {
          column_number: 3,
          filter_type: "text",
          filter_delay: 500
        },
        {
          column_number: 4,
          filter_type: "text",
          filter_delay: 500
        },
    ]);
});
```

and I import the following files:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Export buttons -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/static/datatable/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.0.8.9.js"></script>
    <link href="/static/datatable/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.0.8.9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the jquery ui library - make sure you got the jquery ui slider inside your js, you can get it [from here](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: thanks. it wasn't documented. just wondering - is there a style sheet that you are using, maybe bootstrap like to make it look more modern and cool? and hi from Jerusalem

Comment: It written in the showcase page and on github page too "date input - make use of the jQuery UI Datepicker widget (with some enhancements)" , also you can use Bootstrap datepicker (eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker) , read [docs on how - datepicker_type](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/8e071af195106fa702f942373c65164b89ca40ff/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L244)